# VB.NET List View Delegate

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I've been reading about delegates for a VB.NET project I'm working on. I want use some code in a Background Worker so the the UI remains responsive. The code I wrote involves a List View but I get a cross-thread error. How can I write a delegate for a List View? Examples would be helpful.

Here is the code I want to use in the Background Worker.

```
    If ListViewMain.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ListViewMain.Items.Count - 1
            If ListViewMain.Items(i).Selected = True Then
                If ID3v1ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True Then

                ElseIf ID3v2ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True Then

                ElseIf APEv2ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True Then

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Use Invoke(Sub() TODO) where TODO is an operation on the ListView that you were getting the cross-thread exception.

Comment: Thanks Karen. I'm gonna give that a try.